# Apollo twin and Sterling ST55

Tags: microphone, audio-recording

I plugged my ST55 into the Mic one channel of my Apollo twin.
The cable is XLR and I turn on the +48V phantom power. 
But even if I crank up all the gain to the max in the apollo console, I get  veeeery little signal from the microphone.

[image: Apollo Twin]

[image: microphone][image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you've got the -10dB pad on

Comment: switched back to 0dB same result

Comment: Can you try plugging the microphone into something else to test if it works? Can you also test the XLR cable with something else? Apollo set-up seems correct, can check with mine later.